# Convert a str(numpy array) representaion to a numpy array - Python

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array `a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])`. Now 
`str(a)` will give me `"[1 2 3 4]"`. How do I convert the string `"[1 2 3 4]"` back to a `numpy.array([1,2,3,4])`?

Comment: I would ask why you want to do that instead of just keeping the array, but you can "split" on the spaces.   arr = numpy.array(s.split(' '))

Comment: @ChristianSloper I am writing these numpy arrays to csv files (gets written as shown in example) and i want to be able to read them back as numpy arrays

Comment: Use savetext() from numpy to store them properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `numpy.array([int(v) for v in your_str[1:-1].split()])`